# What is the equivilent of a UITableView in Windows Phone 7 development?

Tags: c#, .net, ios, windows-phone-7

What is the equivilent of a `UITableView` in Windows Phone 7 development?

I'm trying to make the equivalent of a custom `UITableViewCell` with an image on the left and custom `UILabel`s on the right side. Obviously the amount of rows is based on the count of an array of values.

Can someone give me some pointers on what I should do to get the same effect on Windows Phone 7.1?

Comment: I can think of the common `ListBox`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any *list* type of UI element, you would want to use a `ListBox`, with a custom `DataTemplate`.

XAML is more about flexibility, so you don't have specialized UI elements, but instead you can customize a number of base controls to look precisely like you want them.

You probably want a `Grid` inside your `DataTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

There is two controls: `ListBox` for plain list and `LongListSelector` for grouped list (like in contacts)

In both cases you need to set `ItemTemplate`, for ex:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horisontal">
        <Image Source="img.png"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Label"/>  
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```